# How do I associate material with model?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to add a material to a model I have imported to the model's folder and I can't figure out how to do that. People said to drag it on to it but that did not work. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated. BTW, I am on unity 5.3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps -

1. Click on the 3d model.
2. In the inspector panel, expand Mesh Renderer Component.
3. In Mesh Renderer, set material size to 1.
4. Use the small circle button in front of "Material 0" to open a list of available materials in your game.
5. Select the required material by double clicking on it in Material list.

[image: Image for reference]

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the model, on your right side there is the inspector, there is a list of material for that model, just click on it and add the material, or just drag the material from your project folder into the scene on the model.